Find stresses involved and calculate magnitudes
I am new to mechanical design.What all forces and moments act on the hinge plate in following figure?How to find magnitude of stresses induced on the supports?

Note: The spring is an expansion spring and is stretched to 5mm from its normal state.

The spring force varies with the stretch of the spring which in turn varies with the angle of the plate relative to the null position.  I see no value for the angle of the plate relative to any axis.  Thus, the problem is not completely specified and the forces and resulting stresses cannot be determined as drawn.

I have added the missing details.And by hinge plate,i meant the supports.
